# Adding a custom class to DropDownList in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Well here I'm trying to add a Bootstrap class to the DropDownList generated by Razor, but it keeps giving me squigglies.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("NationalityId", String.Empty, new {@class="form-control"})
```

Any recommendation as to how I can get this to work.

Comment: Where do you get the squigglies? What is the error message?

Comment: You are missing two braces at the end:   `} )`

Comment: Sorry the braces are a typo here, syntactically the code is correct, it's probably not the correct overload.

Comment: pass null instead of string.empty, my guess is that you hit wrong overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works:

```
@Html.DropDownList("NationalityId",new List<SelectListItem>(), new {@class="form-control"})
```

Result html:

```
<select name="NationalityId" id="NationalityId" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax, does the NationalityId get passed to the correct table in this case. What does String.empty do anyway?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the resulting HTML in my code? This seems to work and render the correct class though. Thanks

Comment: @Html.DropDownList generates Result html, just use correct overload.  name="NationalityId" - using for correct binding

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
@Html.DropDownList( "NationalityId", null, new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Comment: Does String.Empty and null render the same HTML

Comment: No, but String.Empty was the bug in the line of code, if I am not mistaken. You tried to pass a string where a list was expected. NULL or better yet an empty list (see the other answers) should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
@Html.DropDownList("NationalityId", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),new {@class="form-control"})
```